# Extracting the original image from an Excel comment

Tags: excel, vba, image

We use Excel to log project progress by putting images into cell comments.

We have two issues.

1. Sometimes resizing or deleting rows/columns messes up the aspect ratio, the fix should be re-running the macro that originally added the image using the original image file (or reading the aspect ratio off of the original image file)
2. At the end of the project we want to extract the images at original quality to write the report

I know the original images are there and can be saved by saving the file as .HTML but I cannot find any way to get at that file using VBA.

`CopyPicture` works but only at the quality and aspect ratio of the existing comment, not the underlying image file.

Comment: If you save the file (or a copy of the file) as xlsx and unzip the archive you can find the image files (in `xl\media`), but you'll need to do some work to associate each file with a specific comment.

Comment: I cannot find a file where the images are linked to the comments. It does not appear to be in comments1.xml. Saving the file to temp as a zip, and extracting it does seem like a feasible option if there is a reference in the data that connects a comment and its image.

Comment: If you start with the image file name from the zip and search for that, you will find it (in my case anyway) in "vmlDrawing1.vml.rels" with an associated id (eg) "rId1" - that in turn links to "vmlDrawing1.vml" (o:relid="rId1")  After that I'm not sure where to go but you get the general idea maybe...   I'll take another look later...

Answer (score 0):

The following function will take in a workbook,sheet,cell and return the path to an image file in a temporary working directory if there is an image stored in a comment on the specified cell.

```
Function GetCmtImgPath(WorkbookName, SheetName, CellName) As String
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '1|SETUP AND CLEANUP
    ' Initialize variables
    Dim drawingsFolder As String
    Dim mediaFolder As String
    Dim vmlPath As String
    Dim vmlRelsPath As String
    Dim relid As String
    Dim row As String
    Dim col As String
    Dim line As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ii As Integer
    Dim jj As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim list As String
    Dim filenum As Integer
    Dim inputArray() As String
    Dim outputArray() As Variant
    Dim vmlFileNum As Integer
    Dim relFileNum As Integer
    Dim RelLines As Variant
    Dim relationarray() As Variant
    Dim Id As String
    Dim Target As String
    Dim PicFileName As String
    Dim relFileContents As String
    Dim fileLine As String
    Dim workDir As String
    
    Workbooks(WorkbookName).Sheets(SheetName).Range(CellName).Activate
    
    'Define file paths
    workDir = "C:\temp" 'You can change this if you don't want to use C:\temp
    'these paths should stay fixed
    drawingsFolder = workDir & "\temp_wrkbk\xl\drawings"
    mediaFolder = workDir & "\temp_wrkbk\xl\media"
    vmlPath = workDir & "\temp_wrkbk\xl\drawings\vmlDrawing1.vml"
    vmlRelPath = workDir & "\temp_wrkbk\xl\drawings\_rels\vmlDrawing1.vml.rels"
    'Purge Open Background Files
    For filenum = 1 To 255
        On Error Resume Next
        Close #filenum
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next filenum
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '2|COPY OUT WORKING FILES TO TEMP DIRECTORY
    'Copy the active sheet to a new workbook so we are working with only single-sheet files
    ActiveSheet.Copy

    'Check if the file "tempwrkbk.zip" already exists, and delete it if it does
    If Dir(workDir & "\temp_wrkbk.zip") <> "" Then
        Kill workDir & "\temp_wrkbk.zip"
    End If
    
    'Save the copied sheet as a temporary workbook/zip for extracting the xml files
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=workDir & "\temp_wrkbk.xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Name workDir & "\temp_wrkbk.xlsx" As workDir & "\temp_wrkbk.zip"

    'Set up FSO to handle unziping files
    Dim FSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Delete the folder and its contents if it already exists
     If FSO.FolderExists(workDir & "\temp_wrkbk") Then
        FSO.DeleteFolder (workDir & "\temp_wrkbk")
    End If

    'Create the fresh folder
    FSO.CreateFolder (workDir & "\temp_wrkbk")
    Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace(workDir & "\temp_wrkbk")

    'Extract the contents of the .zip file to the folder
    oFolder.CopyHere oShell.Namespace(workDir & "\temp_wrkbk.zip").Items

    'Cleanup
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oShell = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
    
    'Check for folders present in files with comments and pictures
    If Dir(drawingsFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Or Dir(mediaFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        ' Display message if at least one of the folders doesn't exist
        MsgBox "No comments found", vbExclamation, "Folders not found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '3|SET UP THE FIRST REFERENCE ARRAY WHICH ASSOCIATES CELL AND ID
    'Parse out the Cells and IDs from the vmlDrawing1.vml file

    vmlFileNum = FreeFile()
    ' Open the file
    Open vmlPath For Input As #vmlFileNum
    
   
    ' Read each line of the file
    While Not EOF(vmlFileNum)
        Line Input #vmlFileNum, line
        
        ' Check if the line contains relid, row, and col values
        If InStr(line, "o:relid=") > 0 Then
            relid = Mid(line, InStr(line, "o:relid=") + 9)
            relid = Mid(relid, 2, InStr(relid, Chr(34)) - 2)
        End If
        
        If InStr(line, "<x:Row>") > 0 Then
            row = Mid(line, InStr(line, "<x:Row>") + 7)
            row = Mid(row, 1, InStr(row, "<") - 1)
        End If
        
        If InStr(line, "<x:Column>") > 0 Then
            col = Mid(line, InStr(line, "<x:Column>") + 10)
            col = Mid(col, 1, InStr(col, "<") - 1)
            
            ' Add the relid, row, and col values to the list
            list = list & relid & "," & row & "," & col & ","
        End If
    Wend
    
    ' Close the file
    Close #filenum
    
    ' Input values into a useful VAR array
    inputArray = Split(Left(list, Len(list) - 1), ",")
    ReDim outputArray(UBound(inputArray) / 3, 2)
    For i = 0 To UBound(inputArray) Step 3
        outputArray(i / 3, 1) = Cells(inputArray(i + 1) + 1, inputArray(i + 2) + 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        outputArray(i / 3, 2) = inputArray(i)
    Next i
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '4|SET UP THE SECOND REFERENCE ARRAY WHICH ASSOCIATES ID AND IMAGE FILE
    'Parse out the Cells and IDs from the vmlDrawing1.vml file
    relFileNum = FreeFile()
    Open vmlRelPath For Input As #relFileNum
    relFileContents = ""
    Do While Not EOF(relFileNum)
        Line Input #relFileNum, fileLine
        relFileContents = relFileContents & fileLine
    Loop
    Close #relFileNum
    
    RelLines = Split(relFileContents, "<")
    ReDim relationarray(1 To UBound(RelLines) + 1, 1 To 2)
    For j = LBound(RelLines) To UBound(RelLines)
        ' Extract the Id from the line
        If InStr(RelLines(j), "Id=""") > 0 Then
            Id = Mid(RelLines(j), InStr(RelLines(j), "Id=""") + 5)
            Id = Left(Id, InStr(Id, """") - 1)
        End If

        ' Extract the Target from the line
        If InStr(RelLines(j), "Target=""") > 0 Then
            Target = Mid(RelLines(j), InStr(RelLines(j), "Target=""") + 8)
            Target = Left(Target, InStr(Target, """") - 1)
            PicFileName = Mid(Target, InStrRev(Target, "/") + 1)
            relationarray(j, 1) = Id
            relationarray(j, 2) = PicFileName
        End If
    Next j
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '5|CREATE THE FINAL CELL TO IMAGE REFERENCE ARRAY
    'Replace the id with the image to generate the final reference array
    For ii = LBound(outputArray, 1) To UBound(outputArray, 1)
    For jj = LBound(relationarray, 1) To UBound(relationarray, 1)
        If outputArray(ii, 2) = relationarray(jj, 1) Then
            outputArray(ii, 2) = relationarray(jj, 2)
            If outputArray(ii, 1) = CellName Then
                GetCmtImgPath = mediaFolder & "\" & outputArray(ii, 2)  'Load image into object
                Exit Function
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next jj
Next ii
GetCmtImgPath = Null
End Function
```

Comment: This code is far from optimal, but it achieves the desired function. Edits/improvements are welcome. Thanks @TimWilliams for sending me down the right path.